# Initializing input data

Tags: sapui5

Where, and how do I clear out the input date on a view....

E.g. when the data is saved, and I access my page from the menu, the old data is still displayed in the input boxes.

I've tried the onInit() function but that only fires the first time into the view.

The navto call is in the BaseController which calls the defaultTimes page (view/controller).

```
onNavToDefaultTimes : function(oEvent) {
  this.getRouter().navTo("defaultTimes");
 }
```

My clear code was in the _onRouteMatched function of detaultTimes.....

```
_onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
 var view = this.getView();
 view.byId("shopInput").setValue("");
 view.byId("effectiveDateFrom").setValue("");
 view.byId("shop24Hrs").setSelected(false);
view.byId("shopClosed").setSelected(false);  
},
```

The problem is though, _onRouteMatched is also callled from navBack of the page following default times. And I don't want to clear the fields in this case.

How do I implement the clear from the onNavToDefaultTimes function of the base Controller only?

Can you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of the following options, and put one of them, after the code to save is executed:

Option 1:

```js
var yourInput = this.getView().byId("yourInputID");

yourInput.setValue("");
```

Options 2 (Try someone):

```js
var yourInput = this.getView().byId("yourInputID");

yourInput.unbindValue();
yourInput.unbindElement();
yourInput.unbindObject();
```

Or put the code in the following method, which is executed every time the view is displayed:

```js
onAfterRendering: function(){

   //Option choosed

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is, I need to keep the details when I've navved back from the following page. I've added more details to the question.

Comment: I don't know if I understood what you are now asking... but supose that you want reset/clear the inputs for a specific View (named for example View1), you should put the code for that just in the corresponding Controller (i.e. Controller1).

Also another tip, try as said in my first answer, use/put the code to reset/clear the inputs just when you click the save button, because the _onRouteMatched is invoked any time you navigate to the View, so when you click to navigate the View and with data to show in the inputs, when the method is invoked, the inputs will be cleared/reseted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the name of the view in which your input field is created is test.js, then whenever you are navigating to the view or navigating from the view, you can use invalidate view like below

```
             sap.ui.getCore().byId("test").invalidate();
```

this makes the view to be rendered again when you are coming back to the view and onBeforeRendering() is triggered